# Tabula can't read pdf correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pdf, tabula

i'm trying to extract all tables of my pdf and convert to a structured table in .csv file, but all i got is a csv file in one column.

I have to create a python code to extract all data's on this pdf and save this data in a structured table in csv format

My code:

```
 import tabula import pandas as pd
 
 pdf_path = "./meuPdf.pdf"
 
 tables = tabula.read_pdf(
     pdf_path,
     pages="all",
     pandas_options={"header": None}, )
 
 for i, df in enumerate(tables):
     tables[i] = df.iloc[:, :13]
 
 df_final = pd.concat(tables, ignore_index=True)
 
 if len(df_final.columns) != 13:
     raise ValueError("O número de colunas não é 13")
 
 cols = [
     "PROCEDIMENTO",
     "RN\r(alteração)",
     "VIGÊNCIA",
     "OD",
     "AMB",
     "HCO",
     "HSO",
     "REF",
     "PAC",
     "DUT",
     "SUBGRUPO",
     "GRUPO",
     "CAPÍTULO", ]

 df_final.columns = cols
 
 df_final.to_csv("converted.csv", sep=",", index=False,
 encoding="utf-8")
 
 print(df_final)
```

My csv file:
[image: csv file]

[link to pdf file to extract of tables](https://www.gov.br/ans/pt-br/acesso-a-informacao/participacao-da-sociedade/atualizacao-do-rol-de-procedimentos/Anexo_I_Rol_2021RN_465.2021_RN592.pdf)